# How to restrict region for smart home app?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-smart-home

I'd like to launch smart home app.
But our devices are launching in Japan Only.
So I don't want to display my smart home app on other country users.

How to restrict region for smart home app?

Comment: Please read this [article](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7550024?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

In Action On Google Console, in the Language menu on the left, you have to select each language available for your app, meaning that you will have to enter the metadatas for each language and adapt your app answers so that they adapt to the user language.

This will allow you to publish your app in other countries.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what Remi has said about languages, you can also restrict the location your Smart Home actions will be available in.

From the Actions on Google console, select "Location targeting" and then uncheck "All 213 countries".

[image]

You can then scroll down in the list and select just Japan and click Save.

[image]